# How to add space two positions after each comma in string

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string like:

`st = 0,090,000,170,16-0,030,19 0,330,19`

How to add a spaces into it, two positions after each comma, to get string like:

```
st = 0,09 0,00 0,17 0,16 -0,03 0,19  0,33 0,19
```

Comment: "foreach" through the string, copying character-by-character to a second string. When you see a comma, count (and copy) two more characters and insert extra spaces. Continue until string is done.

Comment: `string result = Regex.Replace(source, @"[0-9]\,", m => " " + m.Value).TrimStart();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Regex.Replace like below

```
var oldString = "0,090,000,170,16 - 0,030,19 0,330,19";
var newString = Regex.Replace(oldString, ",[0-9]{2}", (match) => { return match.Value + " "; });
```